# for loop not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code I want to always begin from 1 but it is not working it continues 5 6 7 8 and so on. I want the value=`{{k}}` always start from 1

```
  <?php  $k=1;   ?>
      @foreach($answers as $answer)
         @if($answer->deleted == 0)
          <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('options.'.$k) ? ' has-error': '' }}"
               id="option{{ $k}}">
            <div class="checkbox col-xs-2 control-label" id="checkbox_control-label">
              <label>

                <input type="text" name="order[{{ $k }}]" value="{{$k}}" id="input_order">


              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" name="options[{{ $k }}]" value="{{ $answer->text}}"
                       class="form-control">
             <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
                <span class="help-block">
                  <strong></strong>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
              <button type="button" value="{{ $k }}" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm"
                      id="delete_option" title="@lang('general.remove_option')">
                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>  
        @endif
       <?php  $k++; ?>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: Move incrementing variable `$k++` inside `if` block before `@endif`

Comment: $K++ is out of if condition

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just increment the variable before end of the if condition:

```
        <?php  $k++; ?>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

$k++ inside if condition .....

```
      <?php  $k=1;   ?>
              @foreach($answers as $answer)
                 @if($answer->deleted == 0)
                  <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('options.'.$k) ? ' has-error': '' }}"
                       id="option{{ $k}}">
                <div class="checkbox col-xs-2 control-label" id="checkbox_control-label">
                  <label>

                    <input type="text" name="order[{{ $k }}]" value="{{$k}}" id="input_order">


                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8">
                    <input type="text" name="options[{{ $k }}]" value="{{ $answer->text}}"
                           class="form-control">
                 <div class="col-xs-12"></div>
                    <span class="help-block">
                      <strong></strong>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-2">
                  <button type="button" value="{{ $k }}" class="btn btn-flat btn-default btn-sm"
                          id="delete_option" title="@lang('general.remove_option')">
                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>  
 <?php  $k++; ?>
            @endif

        @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put at the beginning of the foreach the value to be assigned to `$k` which will be `1`.